# Problem configuring fingerprint sensor

Tags: thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I'm on ThinkPad E14 gen 3, running Ubuntu 20.04.3 which has fingerprint reader, but running `fprintd-enroll` gives me following error:

```
Impossible to enroll: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available
```

Although the fingerprint reader is being detected in `lsusb`

```
27c6:5503 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Goodix FingerPrint Device
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: There does not [appear to be any support](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:27c6-5503) for your fingerprint reader in the Linux kernel just yet. The hardware is visible to Linux but, without someone reverse-engineering a driver that can communicate with that specific device, it will remain non-operational 

Answer (score 2):

Not supported currently in Linux. See [list of supported devices](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html) and [Linux hardware database entry](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:27c6-5503).